# savepoint cannot be resolved to a variable in jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %>
<% 
Connection con = null; PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
String SQL = "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,);
try { Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees", "root", "password");
con.setAutoCommit(false);
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
Savepoint savepoint1 = con.setSavepoint("Savepoint1");
pstmt.setInt(1, 9000);
pstmt.setString(2, "2020-04-04");
pstmt.setString(3, "John");
pstmt.setString(4, "Joe");
pstmt.setString(5, "M");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
con.commit();
out.println("Record is added.");
out.println("<br/>");
} catch (Exception e) {
con.rollback(savepoint1);
out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
} %>
```

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
>   
> An error occurred at line: [38] in the jsp file: [/transaction_pstmt.jsp]
>   
>  savepoint1 cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> 35: 
>   
> 36: } catch (Exception e){
>   
> 37: 
>   
> 38: con.rollback(savepoint1);
>   
> 39: 
>   
> 40: out.println(e.getMessage());
>   
> 41:

And, This is error message.
What's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your code as text (in a code block), not as screenshots.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry, I added my code. Please find error..

Comment: `savepoint1` is defined inside the try-block, so it is limited to the scope of the try-block, you can't use it in the catch-block. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854144/problem-with-scopes-of-variables-in-try-catch-blocks-in-java